# No USB ports recieve power when windows Starts no ps2 ports available

Tags: windows-10, usb, bios

I have this *Acer aspire xc-603* desktop that when i turn on i can use the mouse and keyboard in the bios and bootable usb just fine so i suspect that it is a faulty driver or a power setting in windows that cuts power to the usb ports.

When the machine starts loading windows the num lock light on the keyboard goes off and then light on the mouse aswell.

Troubleshooting steps taken

- Safe Mode (With and without networking)
- Restore Points none of them were sucessful
- sfc scan & Chkdsk in cmd
- tried all usb ports (3.0 & 2.0)
- reset bios

I'm trying to avoid reinstalling windows as the user dosn't know their microsoft account for office.

Comment: Apparently your Win10 installation is lacking proper USB driver. You need to find a way to load the driver.

Comment: It’s literally not possible for that to be true though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed the issue.

Turns out the issue was caused from a windows update i simply put the hard drive in another computer that had ps2 ports and did a windows update.

If i didn't have another computer with ps2 ports my next choice was going to be cloning it to a 2.5" HDD and sticking it in a laptop to use the inbuilt keyboard/touchpad.